# Self-hosted open source alternative to Mailgun for bulk emailing

Tags: open-source, web-apps, email, self-hosted, newsletter

Is there a self-hosted equivalent (not necessarily totally feature equivalent) to services such as Mailgun / Mailchimp et al.?

Core functionality would be email sending, an API, newsletter list maintenance with cancel/subscribe functionality.

I have the requisite knowledge for hosting a web application. Ideally the app would be written in PHP or Node.js but anything open source would do.

Comment: PHP List does this - [www.phplist.org](http://www.phplist.org) - but the interface is fairly dated.